# Cocos2d 2.1 in viewcontroller cant add sprites

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have a view controller which I added a glView, then I simply add to the scene around 100 sprites to test, and got an error in this line of code, this for ios 6 and 7 in any device, compiled with xcode 5

```
/** Appends an object. Bahaviour undefined if array doesn't have enough capacity. */
void ccArrayAppendObject(ccArray *arr, id object)
{
    arr->arr[arr->num] = CC_ARC_RETAIN(object); <-- bad access
    arr->num++;
}
```

this is how I setup the director

```
CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];

if([director isViewLoaded] == NO)
{
// Create the OpenGL view that Cocos2D will render to.
CCGLView *glView = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] bounds]
                               pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565
                               depthFormat:0
                        preserveBackbuffer:NO
                                sharegroup:nil
                             multiSampling:NO
                           numberOfSamples:0];

[director setView:glView];

[director setAnimationInterval:1.0f/60.0f];
[director enableRetinaDisplay:YES];

[director setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection2D];
}


[CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA4444];


CCFileUtils *sharedFileUtils = [CCFileUtils sharedFileUtils];
[sharedFileUtils setEnableFallbackSuffixes:NO];             // Default: NO. No fallback suffixes are going to be used
[sharedFileUtils setiPhoneRetinaDisplaySuffix:@"-hd"];      // Default on iPhone RetinaDisplay is "-hd"
[sharedFileUtils setiPadSuffix:@"-ipad"];                   // Default on iPad is "ipad"
[sharedFileUtils setiPadRetinaDisplaySuffix:@"-ipadhd"];    // Default on iPad RetinaDisplay is "-ipadhd"

director.delegate = (id)self;


[self addChildViewController:director];

[self.view addSubview:director.view];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:director.view];

[director didMoveToParentViewController:self];

layer =[IntroLayer scene];

if(director.runningScene)
    [director replaceScene:layer];
else
    [director runWithScene:layer];
```

and this what I have on the scene init

```
+(CCScene *) scene
{
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];

    for (int i =0; i < 100; i++) {

        CCSprite  *bowSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"icon_clock.png"];

        bowSprite.position = ccp(200,  200);

        [scene addChild:bowSprite];
    }


return scene;
}
```

if someone have any clue it would be very useful

thanks in advance!

Comment: can you make sure `[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"icon_clock.png"]` isn't returning `nil`

Comment: Hi Kevin, thanks for your answer, but I think is returning the sprite quite well, because if I only add one there is no issue, it only happens when I add more that 5, regards!